# Extract one band from a multispectral raster PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, extract, band

I want to extract red band, from a multispectral raster with 5 band, using PyQGIS.

I tried this code, using the GDAL rastercalculator. I tried to extract the 3 bands, and then calculate my index.

```
import processing
entry = r'C:/RASTER.tif'
out = r'C:/RESULT.tif'
parameters = {'INPUT_A': entry, 'BAND_A': '1', 'INPUT_B': entry, 'BAND_B': '2', 'INPUT_C': entry, 'BAND_C': '3', 'FORMULA': ('(BAND_B * 2)- BAND_A - BAND_C)'; 'OUTPUT': out}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:rastercalculator',parameters,feedback=feedback)
```

But I have syntax error.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to get value of the red raster band, right? Or you want to erase-extract-delete the red raster band to make a 4-band raster?

Comment: I want to separate red band, for then calculate diferent RGB indices.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a semicolon within the parameters dictionary where it should be a comma and a wrong bracket. Try:

```
import processing
entry = r'C:/RASTER.tif'
out = r'C:/RESULT.tif'
parameters = {'INPUT_A': entry, 'BAND_A': '1', 'INPUT_B': entry, 'BAND_B': '2', 'INPUT_C': entry, 'BAND_C': '3', 'FORMULA': '((BAND_B * 2)- BAND_A - BAND_C)', 'OUTPUT': out}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:rastercalculator',parameters,feedback=feedback)
```